# Displaying different numbers on 2 seven segment displays on VHDL (Spartan 3)

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise, spartan

We have an assignment about decoding. 4 input switches (binary combination) and displays the corresponding switch combination to 4-LED and decimal value to 1 seven-segment. And convert those binary combination to Grey Code (4 bit also) and display corresponding 4-LED and decimal value to 1 seven-segment.

I already have the solution for the K-Mapping, but my main problem is to print different numbers on both segments. My problem is that it displays the last parsed code. They have the same output to the seven segment.

Here is my code..

```
entity BinaryToGrey is
    Port ( Bin : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              BinLed: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              Enable: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              Segment: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
           Grey : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end BinaryToGrey;

architecture Behavioral of BinaryToGrey is

begin

Grey(3) <= Bin(3);
Grey(2) <= Bin(3) XOR Bin(2);
Grey(1) <= Bin(2) XOR Bin(1);
Grey(0) <= Bin(1) XOR Bin(0);

    process(Bin)

begin
case Bin is
when "0000"=> BinLed <="0000";  -- '0'
        when "0001"=> BinLed <="0001";  -- '1'
        when "0010"=> BinLed <="0010";  -- '2'
        when "0011"=> BinLed <="0011";  -- '3'
        when "0100"=> BinLed <="0100";  -- '4' 
        when "0101"=> BinLed <="0101";  -- '5'
        when "0110"=> BinLed <="0110";  -- '6'
        when "0111"=> BinLed <="0111";  -- '7'
        when "1000"=> BinLed <="1000";  -- '8'
        when "1001"=> BinLed <="1001";  -- '9'
        when "1010"=> BinLed <="1010";  -- 'A'
        when "1011"=> BinLed <="1011";  -- 'b'
        when "1100"=> BinLed <="1100";  -- 'C'
        when "1101"=> BinLed <="1101";  -- 'd'
        when "1110"=> BinLed <="1110";  -- 'E'
        when others => BinLed <="1111"; -- 'F'
    end case;
    end process;


process(Bin,Enable)
begin
        Enable(0) = '0';
        Enable(1) = '1';
        Enable(2) = '1';
        Enable(3) = '0';
        case Bin is 
        when "0000"=> Segment <="1111110";  -- '0'
        when "0001"=> Segment <="0110000";  -- '1'
        when "0010"=> Segment <="1101101";  -- '2'
        when "0011"=> Segment <="1111001";  -- '3'
        when "0100"=> Segment <="0110011";  -- '4' 
        when "0101"=> Segment <="1011011";  -- '5'
        when "0110"=> Segment <="1011111";  -- '6'
        when "0111"=> Segment <="1110000";  -- '7'
        when "1000"=> Segment <="1111111";  -- '8'
        when "1001"=> Segment <="1111011";  -- '9'
        when "1010"=> Segment <="1110111";  -- 'A'
        when "1011"=> Segment <="0011111";  -- 'b'
        when "1100"=> Segment <="1001110";  -- 'C'
        when "1101"=> Segment <="0111101";  -- 'd'
        when "1110"=> Segment <="1001111";  -- 'E'
        when others => Segment <="1001011"; -- 'F'
    end case;

end process;


process(Grey,Enable)
begin

    Enable(0) = '0';
    Enable(1) = '1';
    Enable(2) = '1';
    Enable(3) = '0';
    case Grey is 
        when "0000"=> Segment <="1111110";  -- '0'
        when "0001"=> Segment <="0110000";  -- '1'
        when "0010"=> Segment <="1101101";  -- '2'
        when "0011"=> Segment <="1111001";  -- '3'
        when "0100"=> Segment <="0110011";  -- '4' 
        when "0101"=> Segment <="1011011";  -- '5'
        when "0110"=> Segment <="1011111";  -- '6'
        when "0111"=> Segment <="1110000";  -- '7'
        when "1000"=> Segment <="1111111";  -- '8'
        when "1001"=> Segment <="1111011";  -- '9'
        when "1010"=> Segment <="1110111";  -- 'A'
        when "1011"=> Segment <="0011111";  -- 'b'
        when "1100"=> Segment <="1001110";  -- 'C'
        when "1101"=> Segment <="0111101";  -- 'd'
        when "1110"=> Segment <="1001111";  -- 'E'
        when others => Segment <="1001011"; -- 'F'
    end case;

    end if;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in the code.

**1)** `Enable` is an input, but there are assignments to it. If that signal is for selecting the 7-segment displays, it must be an output.

```
Enable: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
```

**2)** Two processes drive the same `Segment` signal. The assignments should be in one process and they should be multiplexed.

Create a `Select` signal and toggle it every clock cycle. You will also need a clock input for that. (Note: I did not show the generation of `Select` signal)

```
process(Bin,Grey)
begin

if (Select = '0') then -- Select one display

        Enable(0) <= '0';
        Enable(1) <= '1';
        Enable(2) <= '0';
        Enable(3) <= '0';
        case Bin is 
        when "0000"=> Segment <="1111110";  -- '0'
        when "0001"=> Segment <="0110000";  -- '1'
        when "0010"=> Segment <="1101101";  -- '2'
        when "0011"=> Segment <="1111001";  -- '3'
        when "0100"=> Segment <="0110011";  -- '4' 
        when "0101"=> Segment <="1011011";  -- '5'
        when "0110"=> Segment <="1011111";  -- '6'
        when "0111"=> Segment <="1110000";  -- '7'
        when "1000"=> Segment <="1111111";  -- '8'
        when "1001"=> Segment <="1111011";  -- '9'
        when "1010"=> Segment <="1110111";  -- 'A'
        when "1011"=> Segment <="0011111";  -- 'b'
        when "1100"=> Segment <="1001110";  -- 'C'
        when "1101"=> Segment <="0111101";  -- 'd'
        when "1110"=> Segment <="1001111";  -- 'E'
        when others => Segment <="1001011"; -- 'F'
    end case;

else -- Select the other display

    Enable(0) <= '0';
    Enable(1) <= '0';
    Enable(2) <= '1';
    Enable(3) <= '0';
    case Grey is 
        when "0000"=> Segment <="1111110";  -- '0'
        when "0001"=> Segment <="0110000";  -- '1'
        when "0010"=> Segment <="1101101";  -- '2'
        when "0011"=> Segment <="1111001";  -- '3'
        when "0100"=> Segment <="0110011";  -- '4' 
        when "0101"=> Segment <="1011011";  -- '5'
        when "0110"=> Segment <="1011111";  -- '6'
        when "0111"=> Segment <="1110000";  -- '7'
        when "1000"=> Segment <="1111111";  -- '8'
        when "1001"=> Segment <="1111011";  -- '9'
        when "1010"=> Segment <="1110111";  -- 'A'
        when "1011"=> Segment <="0011111";  -- 'b'
        when "1100"=> Segment <="1001110";  -- 'C'
        when "1101"=> Segment <="0111101";  -- 'd'
        when "1110"=> Segment <="1001111";  -- 'E'
        when others => Segment <="1001011"; -- 'F'
    end case;

end if;

end process;
```

**3)** Assert only one bit of `Enable` signal in a clock cycle and use `<=` for the assignments. I assumed `Enable` is active-high. If not, change the values appropriately.

When display 1 is selected:

```
Enable(0) <= '0';
Enable(1) <= '1';
Enable(2) <= '0';
Enable(3) <= '0';
```

When display 2 is selected:

```
Enable(0) <= '0';
Enable(1) <= '0';
Enable(2) <= '1';
Enable(3) <= '0';
```

**4)** `Enable` signal shouldn't be in the sensitivity list. After I merged two processes, it should be as follows.

```
process(Bin,Grey)
```

Comment: One of the positive aspects of using VHDL is declarations tell wonderful stories. Port `Enable` has mode **in**.  See IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.2 Interface object declarations para 14 (in part) *...* ***in.*** *The value of the interface object is allowed to be read, but it shall not be updated by a simple waveform assignment, a conditional waveform assignment, a selected waveform assignment, a concurrent signal assignment, or a variable assignment. ...* Shall has mandatory weight, see 1.3.1.

Comment: Thanks Sir ahmedus!
realized my mistakes with the OUTPUT data type of my enable (using this as anode enable for my segments). Also, used clock as enable for different segment! Thanks. :)

Comment: I'm glad if I could help.